# How to reduce code duplication when using pattern matching and Future mappings?

Tags: scala

I have this code in my one of my controllers:

```
def addPayment(id:String, amount:String) = Action.async(implicit request =>
  User.isBalanceRecordExisting(id).flatMap{
    yesOrNo => yesOrNo match{
      case true => User.getCurrentPaymentBalance(id).flatMap(
        balance => User.updatePayment(id, balance + amount.toDouble)
      ).flatMap(
        result => User.putBonus(id, amount.toDouble, 1)
      ).map(result => Redirect(routes.Application.userBonuses()))
      case false => User.addPayment(id, amount.toDouble).flatMap(
        result => User.putBonus(id, amount.toDouble, 1)
      ).map(result => Redirect(routes.Application.userBonuses()))
    }
  }
)
```

So the logic is simple: I check if there is a record in DB and if it is not there I add it, if it is there then I update it. After that I repeat completely the same chain of actions in both cases.
So I am not happy that in both flows I have duplicated code. Is there a good and concise way to simplify this?
All business logic methods there have some Future[T] return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't use result of add/update, but for keeping your logic this:

```
def addPayment(id:String, amount:String) = {
  def processResult[T](result: T) = User.putBonus(id, amount.toDouble, 1))
    .map(result => Redirect(routes.Application.userBonuses())) 

  Action.async(implicit request => User.isBalanceRecordExisting(id) flatMap {    
      case true => User.getCurrentPaymentBalance(id) flatMap {
                   balance => User.updatePayment(id, balance + amount.toDouble)
                 } flatMap processResult

      case false => User.addPayment(id, amount.toDouble) flatMap processResult
    } 
  )
}
```

UPDATED

Comment: it is not getting compiled. Seems like it does not allow to define methods inside a a controller action body.
It gives me this: 
`illegal start of simple expression
[error] def processResult[T](result:T) = User.putBonus(id, amount.toDouble, 1).map(result => Redirect(routes.Application.userBonuses()))
[error]     ^`

Comment: Sorry, try to add figure brackets.

Comment: thanks. You really helped me and I learned some new things from your help :)